# node/rabbitmq : choreography asynchronous and reponse

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, microservices

Hello I have a question about choreography,

I know it's asynchronous, but in this context:

a requisition in endPoint / addEmployee (where to create an employee the existence in the department is necessary), I would check for an employee and send a message in my department queue to verify the existence and also sign up in the queue to hear the answer, would that be choreography?

Or when confirming the existence of the employee, should I create and send the response already? or can i send the response after consuming the departament queue?

Or in this case, would the orchestration be correct?

Comment: Gabriel in this current shape it is really hard to understand your question. A small diagram could be useful.

Comment: ok sorry, i will try to make the diagram, but basically to create an employee i need the department to exist, and because of that i am having difficulties in messaging modeling

Comment: If I understand correctly you are receiving a request or a message which contains information to create an employee. One of those field is department name or id. And you would like to validate existence of this department information from department service. Is my understanding correct? If so I would say a lot easier solution would be keeping a basic department data on your employee service. You can get department created, updated events from department service and sync your data instead of asking for each and every employee.

Comment: that's exactly it, I didn't understand this purpose that you described, because it is basically I need to validate the existence of the department id in my employee service, and they are different databases, you could give me a practical example, you can abstract as much as possible just for me to assimilate,
I would be very grateful

Comment: it would be like: having a subscribe (orm) with my departaments table, in my department departament, and publishing in an exchange?

Whenever there is an addition update etc. would I send to exchange?

But I wonder how I could save this data to my service employee

Comment: I still think a diagram would be good because even your questions made me confused. The department database most likely managed by some kind of department service. That service can create and send events for you. On your side you can keep a simple table just to fulfill your needs just maybe the name and id of the department.

Comment: I believe I have assimilated your comment, it seems to me to be more performatic than every time I register an employee who would need: connection with rabbitmq, consume queue, publish in queue

and this way: I need to consume only once, and with each update insert I would update via my exchange, but that way I would have a coupling between services

Comment: You wont have a dependency between services. You will just listen the topic or queue to which you wont know where the message comes from which is total opposite of the coupling.

Comment: thank you i believe i have assimilated, i would need to use the subscribe of typeorm / to send new inserts, updates, to my exchange, and would update in my employee service.

Comment: if you could create an answer for me to give you a vote, I would be happy

Thank you for your help

Comment: I created an answer from the comments I put above. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are receiving a request or a message which contains information to create an employee. One of those field is department name or id. And you would like to validate existence of this department information from department service. Is my understanding correct? If so I would say a lot easier solution would be keeping a basic department data on your employee service. You can get department created, updated events from department service and sync your data instead of asking for each and every employee.

With this solution you wont have a dependency between services. You will just listen the topic or queue to which you wont know where the message comes from which is total opposite of the coupling.